# Thymeleaf 3.0 Spring Boot + Security integration does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I struggle to get Thymeleaf to work with Spring Security in my Spring Boot 1.4.3 based project.

Tags like e.g.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
```

are simply not parsed.

If I try to add the `SpringSecurityDialect` manually like this:

```
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}
```

I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/dialect/IExpressionEnhancingDialect
```

I have included the following in my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The `SpringSecurityDialect` does not seem to be added by the autoconfiguration.

After I add the Bean manually, I get the mentioned exception.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

My Thymeleaf versions are:

```
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
<thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>
<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
```

Comment: *Full* stack traces.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37287903/4117061)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get it working, if you are using `Thymeleaf` 3.0.2 with Spring Boot 1.4, you need to force version `3.0.1.RELEASE` of `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` (because it inherits version 2.1.2 which does not work in combination with Thymeleaf 3):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The tags should be using the `hasRole` function.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.RELEASE):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

you need just the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Version of `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` will be inherited from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` and would be [`3.0.2.RELEASE`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/3.0.2.RELEASE).

Thanks to @[yglodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272180/yglodt) for pointing this out.

---

Also in your templates add spring-security namespace `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"` and use `hasRole` instead of `hasAuthority` value in `<sec:authorize>` tag:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: The version of thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 inherited from Spring Boot is 2.1.3. It eventually worked by forcing the version to be 3.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: Do you need to manually create your template engines for this to work?

Comment: @yglodt Thanks for your comment, you are right, I have updated my answer with `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.0.0.RELEASE`.

Comment: @Jolley71717 Thymeleaf is actually a server-side Java template engine itself, it processes HTML (also XML, TEXT, JS, CSS, RAW) templates and generates static HTML pages "on fly". But what about templates - sure, you need manually create them and put your logic there.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem.
Thymeleaf SpringSecurity only works with versions 3.x.x of thymeleaf, and the version that's shipped with Spring-boot is something like 2.x.x atm.

Looking up how to add v3.x.x to my project brought me to the following documentation page:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3

So you just need to add your dependencies, and then add the following in your properties to override the default version of thymeleaf to your dependencies:

```
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
```