# How do I get a Spring boot to parse thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity tags?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a website using Spring Boot for the first time. I am using a test page to show that once the user has logged in, the words, "Authenticated" to appear on the screen when the user has logged in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Thymleaf example</h2>
<p sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    Authenticated
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, problem is that the tag with the sec:authorize remains unedited and unparsed. As a result, the Authenticated word appears regardless of whether a user logged in or not. Printing the user's authorities from controller confirms this.

my pom.xml file has the following dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ... dependencies for mysql and jdbc are omitted.
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Note, I am using Spring Boot, so JAVA configurations are preferred over XML configurations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try adding something like the following code to your `@Configuration`(or `@SpringBootApplication`) class:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver, SpringSecurityDialect sec) {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.addDialect(sec); // Enable use of "sec"
    return templateEngine;
}
```

**Note that if you are forcing Spring Boot to use Thymeleaf version 3, you have to force also the version 3 of the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41393294/3260495).

Comment: Error on the addDialect function.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/dialect/IExpressionEnhancingDialect`
and 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.dialect.IExpressionEnhancingDialect`

Comment: Which version of Thymeleaf are you using? It seems that you don't have the thymeleaf jar in your classpath! Please make sure you have the following lines in your pom.xml and clean your Maven project:

  `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Thymeleaf verison 3.0.2 with the thymeleaf layout dialect being 2.1.1. The dependency tag you types was already in. Other parts of the site I am working on that just use the "th" prefix work fine. It just seems to be thymeleaf-extra-springsecurity tags that are being an issue.

Here is a Pastebin for my entire pom.xml file if you need to see it: http://pastebin.com/TpteH3X4

Comment: Ok, you are forcing Thymeleaf version 3.0.2, so try to add this version tag to your `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency:  `<version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>` (latest version at this moment).

Comment: Also consider to use `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` of `2.1.3.RELEASE` version if the latest one won't work

Comment: Ok, got it working. I just simply stopped forcing the version, had to modify my html template files a bit because of some syntax changes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4(version is 2.1.3.RELEASE),when your thymeleaf version is 2.1.x.Otherwise hasRole in the page of thymeleaf template will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

If it's 2.2.7.RELEASE, then you need Thymeleaf extras for Spring Security 5:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And no extra configuration should be needed.

Answer (score -1):

1) Please add following into your prom.xml file within the  tag to resolve `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.dom.Attribute` Exeption.

```
<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
```

2) Add mentioned in the last post, add the following bean into your `WebSecurityConfig` class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver, SpringSecurityDialect sec) {
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.addDialect(sec); // Enable use of "sec"
    return templateEngine;
}
```

3) Add following dependency, please note about the version, you need to force `3.0.1.RELEASE` version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```